# How is Pareto-domination semi-transitive?

Tags: order-theory

A binary relation $R$ on a set $S$ is

- transitive if $\forall a, b, c \in S: aRb \wedge bRc \Rightarrow aR$c,
- semi-transitive if $\forall a, b, c, d \in S: aRb \wedge bRc \Rightarrow (aRd \vee dRc)$. (see [1,2])

**Any transitive relation is also semi-transitive.**

Let $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The point $\mathbf{u}$ Pareto-dominates $\mathbf{v}$ denoted by $\mathbf{u} \succeq \mathbf{v}$ if $\forall i \in [n]: u_i \leq v_i$ and $\exists j \in [n]: u_j < v_j$. Evidently, Pareto-domination is transitive.

Now let $\mathbf{t} = (0,0)$, $\mathbf{u} = (1,1)$, $\mathbf{v} = (2,2)$ and $\mathbf{w} = (-1,10)$. We get that $\mathbf{t} \succeq \mathbf{u}$, $\mathbf{u} \succeq \mathbf{v}$, however neither $\mathbf{t} \succeq \mathbf{w}$ nor $\mathbf{t} \succeq \mathbf{v}$, so Pareto-domination is **not semi-transitive**. (In fact, $\mathbf{w}$ is non-dominated w.r.t. $\mathbf{t}, \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$.)

**Question**: How is it possible that transitivity implies semi-transitivity, while a transitive relation such as Pareto domination on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not semi-transitive?

What am I missing here? Is the definition of semi-transitivity incomplete?

[1] [Öztürk, Tsoukiàs, and Vincke - Preference modelling](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/volltexte/2006/450/pdf/04271.TsoukiasAlexis.Paper.450.pdf)

[2] [Mayag - Preferences as binary relations](https://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/%7Emayag/Chapitre%201_Binary%20Relations_CentraleSupelec_2019_V2.pdf)

Comment: A simpler counterexample: the equality relation $=$ is transitive, but not semi-transitive according to the definition you have given, if there are at least two points. After all, $a=b=c$ does not imply $a=d$ or $d=c$, since perhaps $d$ is simply another point.

Comment: See alternative meaning of semi-transitive here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/157256/1946 This one is a consequence of transitivity.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Is there a definition of a "semi-transitive" relation that is generally accepted across different fields? The one that I have linked in the sources is commonly found in MCDA/MCDM literature.

Comment: I haven't seen a widely agreed upon definition of this term in logic.